# How to override my database using dependency override in fastapi?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I want to override my database dependency in my pytest. I tried to follow along how dependency override created in the fastapi documentation and try if it overrides but it didnt work and still using the database dependency in my database.py

Here is my **conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from async_generator import asynccontextmanager
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker

from main import create_app
from app.config import settings
from app.service.database.database import session_wrapper
from app.logging import logger

TEST_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+asyncmy://root:password@localhost:3306/sample_db_foo?charset=utf8mb4&binary_prefix=true"

TEST_ENGINE = create_async_engine(TEST_DATABASE_URL)

test_async_sessionmaker = async_sessionmaker(TEST_ENGINE, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)

async def override_session_wrapper():
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def create_session():
        session = test_async_sessionmaker()
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()

    return create_session

app = create_app()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    async with TEST_ENGINE.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

app.dependency_overrides[session_wrapper] = override_session_wrapper

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    yield TestClient(app)
```

and this is my **database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from async_generator import asynccontextmanager

from app.config import settings

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = settings.sqlalchemy_database_base_uri.format(
    mysql_host=settings.mysql_host,
    mysql_user=settings.mysql_user,
    mysql_password=settings.mysql_password,
    mysql_db=settings.mysql_db,
    mysql_charset=settings.mysql_charset,
)

engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)

async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
async def session_wrapper():
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def create_session():
        session = async_session()
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            await session.close()

    return create_session



Base = declarative_base()
```

Did I implemented it wrong?